# mysql - query inside a query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How is it possible to do the following :
(i am using mysql - phpmyadmin )

this query returns a table name :

```
Select table_name from Table1 where id = 1
```

I want to use it inside another query , like :

```
select val from (Select table_name from Table1 where id = 1)
```

but this sure does not work, and since phpmyadmin does not support calling stored procedures, could there be any possible solution for this ?

Comment: And what is `val`? What are you trying to get from `table_name`?

Comment: Explain the real issue, not your incorrect attempt to solve it.

Comment: val is a field common in all the tables , whatever the table name was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really do it in a single `SQL` statement.

You are trying to use `data` (field value) as `metadata` (table name), and `SQL` does not allow this.

You could break it in two statements or write dynamic `SQL` in a stored procedure. Note that not all client layers support returning resultsets from stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

you also ma execute dynamic select:

```
declare v_table_name VarChar(128);
BEGIN 

Select table_name into v_table_name from Table1 where id = 1
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', v_table_name, ' where id = 1'); 
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 

END;
```