# SQL construct query from result

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Given a table rules

```
rule_id = 1
rule_condition = 'size > 15'
```

how can I run a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM rawdata where (Select rule_condition FROM rules WHERE rule_id=1)
```

Is the only way to do it a stored procedure like this: [mysql - query inside a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490819/mysql-query-inside-a-query)

Comment: What records are you wanting?  The exmple just returns the same result as the nested query..

Comment: Your query has table rawdata, which isn't joining to the subquery. Try adding a join condition, i.e. where rawdata.column = (select rule_condition...)

Comment: Do you want the outer SQL `SELECT * FROM rawdata` to be executed with a fully dynamic `WHERE` clause? In your example you want the query to return the results of `SELECT * FROM rawdata WHERE Size > 15` ?

Comment: Lets backup for a sec..  Essentially you want a select statment to return a record set for rule_id = 1 and rule_condition = 'size > 15'  correct?   What type of column is rule_condition (what type of data is stored there)

Comment: @Carpe: in the rawdata table there would be records like size = 10 and size = 17 of these I want only the ones matching the condition, so in

Comment: @Shan I don't see why joining rawdata into the subquery would help, the subquery returns 'size > 15' which is the condition

Comment: and is the contents of the field literally "size > 15" or is it just "15"  ?

Comment: @Simen yes I want it to be dynamic and yes the example would be SELECT * FROM rawdata WHERE Size > 15

Comment: @Carpe the content is literally "size >15" so that the where condition is dynamic. On another rule the rule_condition would be "color LIKE '%blue%'"

Comment: @Civic I see now what you're trying to do. You'll have to use dynamic SQL

Comment: @Cilvic: DING okay i get it.. You are simpy trying to store the WHERE clause in the database...  RIght?  (if so i was having a blond moment)

Comment: What RDBMS are you on? You link to MySQL docs here but your previous question seemed to be SQL Server?

Comment: @martin I am on MS SQL, sorry I didn't realize the other example was MySQL

Comment: @Cilvic - In that case the answer you accepted won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is essential reading for you before starting with dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

For SQL Server you would use something like...

```
DECLARE @dynamicsql NVARCHAR(1000)

SELECT @dynamicsql =N'SELECT * FROM rawdata where ' + rule_condition 
FROM rules 
WHERE rule_id=1

IF(@@ROWCOUNT = 1)
   EXEC(@dynamicsql)
```

Hopefully you are not planning on allowing users to enter arbitrary `rule_condition` s as they could execute any arbitrary statements against your SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks, I will try as soon as I have access to my server, the rule_condition won't be public

Answer (score 2):

```
declare whereClause VarChar(128);
BEGIN 

Select rule_condition into whereClause FROM rules WHERE rule_id=1
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM rawdata where ', whereClause;) 
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 

END
```

This should get you close.

Note this will only work if the first select that selects a string into `whereClause` is a single record.